# EclipseLink FetchGroup fetching inherited attributes

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible to use FetchGroup when the entity you are fetching has a reference to an abstract class but you want to fetch an attribute that belongs only to one of the possible inheriting classes.

For example...

A pet has an owner (owner is an abstract class) and an owner can be a person or a shelter. A person has an attribute... lets say age, and I want that.

```
public Pet findPetSlim(Integer id) {
   Pet result = null;
   FetchGroup group = new FetchGroup("PetSlim");
   group.addAttribute("id");
   group.addAttribute("owner.age");  //this will not work because owner doesn't have age
   Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("Select p from Pet p where p.id = :id").setParameter("id", id);
   q.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH_GROUP, group);
   result = (Pet) q.getSingleResult();
   return (result);
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get back from shelter instances?  Why not just query for pets with owners that are people, such a "select p from Pet p join TREAT(p.owner AS Person) person where p.id=:id" in JPA 2.1 or use a query that returns just data instead of entities like "select pet.id, owner.age from Person owner, Pet pet where pet.id = :id and pet.owner = owner".  You can use the second query to return entities with the fetchGroup as needed as well.

Comment: Well I can't just only pull Pets with Owners that are Person, I need all Pets. Just later on I need age if the Owner is a Person. You'd say why not just pull the entire Owner, well Owner is very complex and has a lot of bi-directional relationships which causes performance issues.

Comment: Since I do not think this is possible I went ahead and added another query when age is needed if the Owner is a Person. I was trying to limit the amount of queries because this additional query will be a remote interface call =(